# Derive state space from initial value problem

Tags: state-space, control-theory

I am given the following initial value problem
\$ y^{(4)} - y = u  \$ with \$ y^{(3)}(0)=0,  \ddot{y}(0)=1, \dot{y}=1, y(0)=10  \$
and am supposed to calculate the state space in the usual form

\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = f(x,y) \end{equation}

\begin{equation}y = h(x,y) \end{equation} with
\begin{equation}
x^T = \begin{bmatrix}
         x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 
     \end{bmatrix}
:= 
\begin{bmatrix}
         y & \dot{y} +\ddot{y} & \dot{y} -\ddot{y} & y^{(3)}
     \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

The initial values are non-zero, so Laplace transform and calculating \$ G(s) \$ as \$ \frac{Y(s)}{U(s)} \$ and then deriving the state space from the transfer function \$ G(s) \$ wont work, since we will get:

\begin{equation} s^4Y(s)-s^3y(0)-s^2\dot{y}(0)-s^\ddot{y}(0)-y^{(3)}(0)-Y(s) = U(s) \end{equation}

\begin{equation} s^4Y(s)-10s^3-s^2-s-Y(s) = U(s) \end{equation}

\begin{equation} Y(s)(s^4-1)-10s^3-s^2-s = U(s) \end{equation}

And \$ -10s^3-s^2-s \$ is a problem here

---

So i did it the usual way and transformed the 4th order DE into a 1st order DE-system.

\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
         \dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2 \\ \dot{x}_3 \\ \dot{x}_4 
     \end{bmatrix}
     =
     \begin{bmatrix}
         0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 \\ 
         0 & 0.5 & -0.5 & 0 \\   
         0 & -0.5 & 0.5 & 0 \\   
         1 & 0 & 0 & 0   
     \end{bmatrix}
      \times
     \begin{bmatrix}
         x_1 (=y) \\ x_2(=\dot{y}+\ddot{y}) \\ x_3(=\dot{y}-\ddot{y}) \\ x_4(=y^{(3)})  
     \end{bmatrix} 
     + 
     \begin{bmatrix}
         0 \\ 0 \\ 0\\ 1
     \end{bmatrix}
     u
\end{equation}

I think this should be right. Now, how do i implement the initial values in this state space?

---

Later i am supposed to execute a linear state transform to

\begin{equation}
         \dot{z} = \tilde{A}z+\tilde{B}u
     \end{equation}
\begin{equation}
         y = \tilde{C}z+\tilde{D}u
     \end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
z^T = \begin{bmatrix}
         z_1 & z_2 & z_3 & z_4 
     \end{bmatrix}
:= 
\begin{bmatrix}
         y & \dot{y} & \ddot{y} & y^{(3)}
     \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

but i think i can not execute the linear state transform just now, since the initial values are not represented in the state space above, as of now.

Here are a few theorems, Theorem 4 is just the linear state transformation, Theorem 5 is just matrix exponentials,  Theorem 6 i sadly dont really get what its used for and Theorem 7 is just stating that the output response is invariant under a linear state transformation.

Does any of these Theorems, especially Theorem 6 have to do with initial conditions?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> how do i implement the initial values in this state space?

they are literally the initial condition of the ODE, they won´t show up on the definition of \$\dot{x}\$ but on the definition of \$x(0)\$ (or whichever point you choose as the starting one of the trajectory.)

> but i think i can not execute the linear state transform just now, since the initial values are not represented in the state space above, as of now.

If you have the system

$$ \begin{align} \dot{x} &= Ax +Bu \\ x(0) &= x_0\end{align} $$

and you transform \$x\$ into \$z = Tx\$, where \$T\$ is a square matrix of appropriate size, you can then find \$\dot{z}\$ which will be

$$ \begin{align} \dot{z} &= T\dot{x} = TAx + TBu \\ z(0) &= Tx(0)\end{align} $$
lastly, for an invertible \$T\$ we have that \$x = T^{-1}z\$.

Comment: So you dont even include it in the state space itself but just put all initial conditions below? So i can just transform the state space from \$ x \$ to \$ z \$ at this point already? What about the zero-initial state and zero-input response? \begin{equation} x(t) = x_h(t) + x_p(t) \end{equation} I also have these weird formulas : \begin{equation}  x(t) = e^{At}x_0 + \int_{0}^t e^{A(t)-\tau}  Bu(\tau)d\tau \end{equation}   \begin{equation}  y(t) = Ce^{At}x_0 + \int_{0}^t Ce^{A(t)-\tau}  Bu(\tau)d\tau+Du(t)\end{equation}  I dont need them for this exercise?

Comment: I cant add photos in the comments so i will add a few theorems which confuse me and i thought i will need to use for this exercise. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dont \$ A,B,C \$ and \$ D\$ need different multiplications with \$ T^{-1}\$  and \$ T\$ looking at Theorem 4 above? Thanks a lot, i really appreciate your help!

Comment: Well, if you read it carefully you will notice that I defined \$z = Tx\$ while the Theorems you later added define \$x = Tz\$, that is why all that is \$T\$ on my equations becomes \$T^{-1}\$ in your book.

Comment: You are dealing with a linear ODE, that is why you can decouple the response to initial conditions and to the input \$u(t)\$

Comment: Sorry, i did not see that, but shouldnt it be \$ TAT^{-1}, TB \$ with your transformation "substitution" then? Notice the \$ T^{-1} \$ that is not present in your answer. Maybe i am wrong though... Its getting late. Thanks for the kind explanation! Do you mean \$ z \$ and \$ x\$ as vectors with \$ z(0)= Tx \$ ? Otherwise i dont really get it, since \$ z(0) \$ would just equal a scaled matrix and not a scalar. I assume i just have to put all initial conditions in a vector by ascending or descending order and thus have vector equals Matrix Times vector. Is that correct?